# PDF Automation with Typeform and GoogleSpreadsheet

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, automation, spreadsheet

I need some help about the best way to do a small automation project.

I have created a form using Typeform. At the end of the form, the answers are automatically send to a Google Spreadsheet using Zapier. Now, I want to generate a PDF and send it to the user each time there is a new entry in my form. I was thinking to use Google Script (JavaScript) to do so.

The tricky part is that my form is dynamic: if the user answers A to question 1, he will jump to question 2. Else, he will directly jump to question 3 and never see question 2. So, I will have empty rows in my answer’s spreadsheet and won’t be able to just copy/paste the answers. So I am wondering: are Google Spreadsheet and Google Script the best way to generate a pdf based on answers submitted to a form? Is there another better technology to do it?

Thank you for your advices,

Romain

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [autocrat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocrat/ppgnklghfnlijoafjjkpoakpjjpdkgdj). However, as your form is dynamic autocrat won't be able to dynamically build your document, if a cell is empty the field in the doc will be empty too.

It is possible to build a custom script to create a dynamic doc based on the information submitted to the sheet but that would require knowledge of the Google App Script coding.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Unfortunately, I can't have empty cells as my form is dynamic and has a lot of options... It looks like I need to learn the Google App Script basics.